# Laich vs. Leiche

Tags: etymology, difference

Gibt es eine Verbindung zwischen diesen Begriffen? Wie kommt es, dass so gegensätzliche Dinge so ähnliche Namen haben (Laich ist der Beginn des Lebens von beispielsweise Fröschen, wobei eine Leiche das Ende des Lebens bedeutet).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Es gibt keine Verbindung zwischen *Laich* und *Leiche*.

*Leiche* stammt vom mittelhochdeutschen *lîch* ab, was so viel wie Körper und Leib bedeutet und bereits früh für den *toten Körper* verwendet wurde. <sup>[DUDEN](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Leiche)</sup>

*Laich* hingegen entstammt vom mittelhochdeutschen *leich*, was die Nebenbedeutung Liebesspiel hat. <sup>[DUDEN](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Laich)</sup>
Der mittelhochdeutsche Begriff *leich* (Tonstück, gespielte Melodie, Gesang) bezeichnet eigentlich einen Minnesang, also die Verehrung einer (adligen) Dame in Form gesungener Liebeslyrik (mehr dazu auf der WP Seite für [Minnesang](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minnesang)). 
Bekanntlich werden im Tierreich die Weibchen unter anderem durch Tänze beeindruckt. Sozusagen ein Liebestanz. Wie bereits erwähnt, bedeutet *leich* ebenfalls Liebestanz.

Da sich *Leich* aber dem Wort *Leiche* ähnelt, ersetzte man anscheinend das *e* durch ein *a*.
Im Buch [Wörter und Namen gleicher Herkunft und Struktur](http://books.google.de/books?id=X_dv14TWVxcC&pg=PA195&lpg=PA195&dq=laich%20wortherkunft&source=bl&ots=dRggwlFB7V&sig=1rKY7xIRhisUpnLY0awPOaG0sfg&hl=de&sa=X&ei=4jocT-fdOoeg-AbN4pGnCA&ved=0CD0Q6AEwAw#v=onepage&q&f=false) wird darauf hingewiesen, dass die heutige Schreibweise im 18. Jahrhundert zur Unterscheidung von Leiche eingeführt wurde.

Answer (score 3):

Das mittelhochdeutsche "lîch" für "Leiche" hat seinen Einzug interessanterweise auch in die englische Sprache gefunden. Als "lychgate" bezeichnet es heute noch das meist überdachte Tor zum Friedhof bzw. zum Kirchhof; der Ort, wo der Sarg eines Verstorbenen wartet, bis die Beerdigungszeremonie anfangen kann.